# pull data from two tables

Tags: php, sql

I need to pull data from two tables, and it's a bit over my head :

The first tables contains a list of members (member_id, username, email ...)
The second table stores relations between members (id, member_id, friend_id)

When a member adds another member as a friend, both member_ids are stored in the second table.

Now I need to output that second table, I'd like to output usernames instead of numbers :

example :

**{username corresponding to member_id}** added **{username corresponding to friend_id}** as a friend

Can someone help with the query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
select tb1.username as member_name,
       tb2.username as friend_name
from   membertable as tb1
inner join
(
       membertable as tb2,
       memberrelationstable
)
on
(
    tb1.member_id = memberrelationstable.member_id and
    tb2.member_id = memberrelationstable.friend_id
)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help ! I don't understand what is tb1 and tb2 ? Are these some kind of temporary tables ?

Comment: They're aliases, as you're using the same table twice in your select, but referencing different records each time (one time you want the member record, one time the friend record) you can give the tables aliases (and the fields aliases of member_name and friend_name as you want the same field twice) so you can differentiate between them.

Comment: Try reading here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp and here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp, it breaks it down quite well so might be easier to understand.

Comment: What I dont understand in your code is I don't have username in relations table, I only have member_id and friend_id, so I can't do your tb2.username

Comment: tbl1 and tbl2 are both the member table, neither of them is relations. Because you want two records from the same table you need to nickname the tables (so tb1 and tb2) so you can refer to each record without confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform a double join on members

```
SELECT mem1.username, mem2.username
FROM members mem1 
 INNER JOIN relations
   ON mem1.member_id = relations.member_id
 INNER JOIN member mem2
   ON relations.friend_id = mem2.member_id
```

Comment: ommitting the implicit AS was a bit confusing, but thanks for your help I understand now

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
SELECT member.username AS member_username, friend.username AS friend_username
FROM relations

INNER JOIN members AS member
ON relations.member_id = member.member_id

INNER JOIN members AS friend
ON relations.friend_id = mem2.member_id
```

I've spaced it so that you can easily see how we're joining the members table twice, and simple giving it a different name both times.

Whenever something is followed by AS, it means that you're giving it another name. This allows you to use the same table multiple times in a single query.